# How to force Java to reload environment variables

Tags: java, exec, environment-variables

I have a java program that launches a C compiled program via Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command). This "command" uses an environment variable.

If the java program is still running but the env varaible is changed (by another external process) before calling exec(command), then the C program will still have the old env value.

It seems the C program is getting it's environment from the main Java process as the env value is correct when the java process is restarted. Is there a way to force the env variable to be refreshed inside the Java process?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Java - just how to reload environment variables when starting a child process.

Comment: @djechlin no the OP wants to load the changed environment into the Java program

Comment: @Mark but that is a OS issue, Java gets its environment like any other program

Comment: I have to point out that saying "the env variable is changed" is a nonsense-phrase.  Changed means "with respect to the environment," and "the environment" in this case means "a different one."  So what environment are you (nosily) listening to env variable changes in, and why on earth?

Comment: To clarify, the C program I am calling is a vendor's program so I have no control of it. My Java code knows nothing about his env variables nor should it care. The problem is that it appears when the JVM is started, it gets the env values from the OS and passes those env values when spawning a process using runtime.exec. So process A that gets spawned uses the env variable. When needed process A is terminated and Process B runs and it eventually updated the env variable. Process A is restarted again. But the 2nd startup of process A does not see the updated value that was set by process B.

Comment: Try exploring Apache's commons-exec project. It is very rich in this manner.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use environment variables.

The behavior that you're describing is [how environment variables work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Synopsis). Changes that you make to the environment of a process are propagated to its children. However, changes that a child makes are not propagated back to the parent, nor do arbitrary processes update one-another.

The simplest alternative is a configuration file stored in a well-known location.

Comment: I wish I could get around not using the env variable but it is the vendor's program that I'm spawning and he is the one making use of the variable (that can't be changed). It is a 2nd processing (also vendor owned) that updates the env var. We are just trying to automate this process of calling both exe's thru our java program instead of the user manually clicking on the vendor's icons.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java Application can store the value of the environment variable as soon as you launch the C application, then you use a thread class that will be always running. This thread class will be  always checking if the environment variable has changed, that's why we saved the previous value of the environment variable, so if it changes, then you have no option but to execute your C program again through the Runtime.

for instance:

```
//inside your thread
if (!envVar.equals(envVarPReviousValue)) { 
//execute again
Runtime.getRumtime().exec("C-app");
}
```

Comment: a dedicated pool thread. Yes, I had a similar requirement in my job and we solved that way. It was useful and it is not too heavy as it seems.

Comment: How do you check that the environment variable has changed?  I'm pretty sure this is nonsensical.

Comment: would the Java app be able to actually check if a child process (via runtime.exec) changed the env var? My java program calls two child processes, first process reads and uses the env var, then 2nd process updated the env var when required. When it is time to run the 2nd process, the 1st process is killed then restarted when the 2nd process completes. My Java program doesn't use the env var at all. Both child processes will never execute at the same time.